# static page inside Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In wordpress when I make a contact form and I call a testmail.php file which is sending the email? Because when I call the file example: hostname/a/testmail.php -> Page not found. The directory a/testmail.php inside the themes/ownthemes folder, but I cannot reach the testmail.php.

This approach is it possible?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Please don't create another entry point inside WP theme.
There are well made plugins for sending forms: https://wordpress.org/plugins/ninja-forms/ https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

If you really want to build your own script please use AJAX action https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)
or some other hook to run your code inside WP environment.

Creating entry point inside your theme leads to code duplication and security issues.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Instead of calling `hostname/a/testmail.php`, you need to call `hostname/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/a/testmail.php`. Or place the file in the http root (where the wp-content, wp-admin, etc. folders are).
This is a way to get it going and working quickly, but I will suggest using an AJAX action like Kostya answered if you want to go for better production value.

Answer (score 0):

So it's a good idea to use plugins such as : contact form7 to deal with such function 
And if you still need to call outside script written on php but having trouble with that(getting 404 error) you are getting this because of the .htaccess file of the wordpress / the host. 
sample :

```
    IndexIgnore *

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \\.(gif|jpg|js|css)$ - [F]

# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteRule ^index\\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```